# Storport Miniport driver

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

The storport driver stack shows flow as follows.
STorage Class driver -> Storage Filter driver -> Storage port driver -> Storage MIniport driver

How does this hierarchy apply in case of storport drivers.

1. Can the Storage port and Storage miniport be implemented in the same sys file.
2. Which is better to design Storport or scsi port for a storage controller?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but in doing so, you have rejected the port model.
2. Storport was designed as the high-performance replacement to scsiport.

Comment: A few more queries.  1. I have both storport.sys and scsiport.sys on win2k8 c:\windows\system32\drivers folder. How do I know which driver is being used internally by my storage array controller driver.